# Display prompt before ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, prompt

I'm trying to get a user entering the reason for updating qty before ajax submits the qty to db.

This is jquery code which sends qty change to the php script which updates db. For some reason, I can't stop ajax and display a prompt for a user to display so he could write a reason why he is updating qty. Can someone tell me why prompt is not being displayed?

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="update_qty.php">
<input type="text" name="update_qty" class="update_qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $sales_value['qty'] ?>"><?php echo ' Kom'; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="<?php echo $sales_value['article_id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sales_plan_id" id="sales_plan_id" value="<?php echo $sales_plan_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="product_mix_id" id="product_mix_id" value="<?php echo $product_mix_id; ?>">
</form>

    //Update qty on article
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.update_qty').on('change', function() {

        var message = prompt("Upišite razlog za izmjenu količine:");
        alert(message);
        //e.preventDefault();
        var article_id = $("#article_id").val();
        var sales_plan_id = $("#sales_plan_id").val();
        var update_qty = $(this).val();
        var product_mix_id = $("#product_mix_id").val();


        if (message != "" || message != NULL) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'update_qty.php',
                data:{ article_id: article_id, sales_plan_id: sales_plan_id, update_qty: update_qty, product_mix_id: product_mix_id, message: message },
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            e.PreventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Your code works fine [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KeaGNo?editors=1011). Any error in console?

Comment: No error, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: If you add a `console.log("hello");` right before `//e.preventDefault();`, do you see it in console when blurring?

Comment: Yes, I can see it. It's strange if I change event to "change" than prompt is displayed but only for the first row. When is an event "blur" than it's not displayed at all?

Comment: Well... What is the element? is it an `<input>`?

Comment: Yes, it's input. <input type="text" name="update_qty" id="update_qty" value="<?php echo $sales_value['qty'] ?>"><?php echo ' Kom'; ?>

Comment: Are you looping in PHP, to create the rows? An ID must be unique. So if you use the same ID on each row, that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's same ID on each row. Loop is in php. How do I fetch dynamic ID with on change event?

Comment: Use a class. Replace all `id="update_qty"` with `class="update_qty"` and then use `.update_qty"` as a selector for the script. You have to look for the other ids too... [**Read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: OK, I did that and is working, but now I have a problem that I don't know which row I'm updating? How to get the value of the row that is changed?

Comment: change `var update_qty = $("#update_qty").val();` with `var update_qty = $(this).val();`

Comment: Use `$(this)` and [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

Comment: OK, that is solved. Only one more thing that is not working. How to pass prompt message to php? You can see my updated code which is working now.

Comment: That is a new question. Post a new question for that.

Comment: I just saw that hidden fields are not fetched anymore. I get only first row for them? How do I dynamicly fetch hiddent fields same as I did with update qty?

Answer (score 0):

try like this using `beforesend`.

Update:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var message;

      $('#update_qty').on('blur', function() {

    //e.preventDefault();
    var article_id = $("#article_id").val();
    var sales_plan_id = $("#sales_plan_id").val();
    var update_qty = $("#update_qty").val();
    var product_mix_id = $("#product_mix_id").val();



      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        beforesend:con(),
        url:'update_qty.php',
        data:{ article_id: article_id, sales_plan_id: sales_plan_id, update_qty: update_qty, product_mix_id: product_mix_id },
        success:function(data) {
          alert(data);
        }
      });


  });

});

function con(xhr){
    message=prompt('enter reason');
    if(message==''){
     xhr.abort();

     }
    }
```

Comment: No, prompt is not displaying. It goes to update_qty.php

Comment: by mistake i used `;` instead of `:` and by changing this too old method wont work so  use updated working method